# How do we handle image with filepath and convert to base64 in react hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-context

How do we handle and convert into base64, if we receive `image with path` in React Hook in following format:  `images\photo-1592376542020.JPG`

`UserLoginProvider.js`

```
import { UserProfileContext, UserLoginContext } from '../context';

const UserLoginProvider = ({children}) => {

    const [loginPhoto, setLoginPhoto] = useState({ photo:''});

     const value = useMemo(() => ({
        loginPhoto, setLoginPhoto
    }), [loginPhoto]);


    return (
       <UserLoginContext.Provider value={value}>
           {children}
       </UserLoginContext.Provider>
    )   
}
export default UserLoginProvider;
```

`Navigation.js`

```
const [loginImgSrc, setLoginImgSrc] = useState(null);
const { loginPhoto } = useContext(UserLoginContext);

// While doing console.log("Print here:"+loginPhoto);  displays [object object ] 
    useEffect(() => {
            if (loginPhoto.photo) {
            const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.addEventListener('load', () => {
               setLoginImgSrc(reader.result);
               console.log("LoginImage:"+reader.result);
               localStorage.setItem("loginImgData", reader.result);
            });
            reader.readAsDataURL(loginPhoto.photo);
            }
        }, [loginPhoto.photo])

        var loginImage = localStorage.getItem('loginImgData');

<span className="image_login_link"><img className="nav_profile" src={loginImage}></img></span>
```

Comment: refer this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22172604/convert-image-url-to-base64

Comment: @JingJiang Not working Jing, I have tried many options.

Comment: `function base64Encode(file) {
        var body = fs.readFileSync(file);
        return body.toString('base64');
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        if (loginPhoto.photo) {
        var base64String = base64Encode(loginPhoto.photo);
        setLoginImgSrc(base64String);
        localStorage.setItem("loginImage", base64String);
        }
    }, [loginPhoto.photo])

    var loginUserImg = localStorage.getItem('loginImage');`

Comment: The most recent image to base64 is the above one. I have no error, but still image is not displaying